# Installing Turtlebot3 software for the first time on remote pc

Tags: turtlebot3

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am up to the point of starting up the software on the remote pc. I am following the tb3 wiki. I gave this command:

```
pitosalas@pitothink:~$ roslaunch turtlebot3_bringup turtlebot3_model.launch
```

I am getting this error message:

```
[turtlebot3_model.launch] is neither a launch file in package [turtlebot3_bringup] nor is [turtlebot3_bringup] a launch file name
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

- I am not sure what directory I should be in when issueing the above command
- Also where can I find the log file?

Thanks!

Pito

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/266428/installing-turtlebot3-software-for-the-first-time-on-remote-pc/) by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 628 on 2017-07-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can run that command from anywhere. The problem is that ROS can't find the package `turtlebot_bringup`. You need to make sure that you

- install the package using `apt-get` or from source.
- if you downloaded it from the source, put it in the `src` directory of your `catkin` workspace
- go to the root of your `catkin` workspace and run either `catkin_make` or `catkin build` (which ever is recommended)
- run `source devel/setup.bash` (again, from the root of your `catkin` workspace)

Now, you should be able to run that command.

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2017-08-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I assume you're following this: http://turtlebot3.robotis.com/en/latest/bringup.html

Assuming you have the ros master hostname on your turtlebot directed at the ip of your remote PC, you need to run roscore on you remote PC and run the bringup command on the turtlebot. There are a couple of ways to do this:

1. open up terminal on the turtlebot and run the launch bringup
2. ssh from your remote PC and run the launch bringup
3. create a startup script that executes the bringup when the turtlebot turns on

Other than the bringup, everything else(navigation, SLAM, teleop) can all be run from your remote PC.

---

Originally posted by [xnick77x](https://answers.ros.org/users/30994/xnick77x/) with karma: 77 on 2017-07-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1